# MySQL slow copy from one to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, copy

I copied files from one database to another using the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO database1.table Select ... FROM database2.table
```

It works all fine but is really really slow. For 400.000 datarows (about 600mb) it took me a couple of hours.

I am using an MyISAM table to do it.

My primary key is a unique identifier which is build out of different datafields.

Could I speed up the copying process by adding a new column which uses an unique identifier, let's say an integer which begins at 1 and goes to the last row and make it an AUTO_INCREMENT which also goes up when copying the files?
Or maybe setting an index on the new column?

I am really happy if you can help me speed up the copy process.

Comment: In addition to the advice given in the answers, also you can find others in [8.2.2.1. Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-speed.html) and [8.6.2. Bulk Data Loading for MyISAM Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Stop using the crappy MyISAM engine if you can. It's very fast for reads, but write performance can be brutal, and often the whole table will get locked to maintain consistency as there's no support for transactions. InnoDB handles concurrent writes much better, and has the additional benefit of being journaled so your tables are far less likely to get completely trashed if your server isn't shut down correctly.

Step 2: Disable indexes on your target table, or delay creating them until you've inserted data. Updating indexes can add significant overhead. You're doing this as a one-shot insert, so the penalty is lower, but still non-zero.

Comment: Hey tadman, thanks for your advice! I copied all my data in a new table which now uses the InnoDB. After this I disabled the index and as you said, my DB was much faster.

Answer (score 2):

The speed of copying from one table to another is highly dependent on many things, so it's hard to give one single "this is the answer."

Off the top of my head here are a few things that might be issues:

1. It appears that you are copying from a table in one database to a table in another database.  If these two databases are on the same physical disk then you will have some performance penalty as the disk seeks, reads, seeks, writes.
2. Does the destination table have an index?  If so MySQL is probably indexing at the same time of data insertion.  That can greatly slow down data copy.  It would be FAR faster to disable the index, copy the data, then enable the index.
3. MySQL has a lot of tuning parameters for caching, memory management, and so forth.  These settings might be suboptimal for copying data.  It's been a while since I've worked with MySQL, but I remember there was a data tuning tool that would read the logs and tell you where the performance hits are coming from.

I've worked with databases containing literally billions of rows.  When I had to do bulk inserts or bulk copies the indexing was a huge performance penalty.  You didn't show us the structure of the tables, but #2 above should be looked into seriously.

Comment: Hey Isaac, thanks your answer! I am quite new to databases but you really helped me out. To 1, yes they are two databases on one server, which will make it slow. To 2, by removing the index it speed up immediately! For further improvements I will also look for the tool you mentioned in 3.